# How to load div elements from specific class from external page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load `<h3>` elements from divs with a defined class from external website. 
I specifically want to get the titles.
The external website is not mine and I can change anything in its html.
Part of this website's html is something like this

```
<div id="container">

<!-- some other divs -->
<div class="content sub">

    <div class="box blog">
        <h3><a href="http://www.somelink.com/page1/" title="">Title 1</a></h3> 
        <p>Some text here... bla bla bla...</p>
        <a href="http://www.somelink.com/page1/" title=""  class="read_more">read more</a>
    </div>  

        <div class="box blog">
        <h3><a href="http://www.somelink.com/page2/" title="">Title 2</a></h3> 
        <p>Some text here... bla bla bla...</p>
        <a href="http://www.somelink.com/page2/" title=""  class="read_more">read more</a>
    </div>

        <div class="box blog">
        <h3><a href="http://www.somelink.com/page3/" title="">Title 3</a></h3> 
        <p>Some text here... bla bla bla...</p>
        <a href="http://www.somelink.com/page3/" title=""  class="read_more">read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to load the titles in a jQuery Mobile page - in its content div.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If it's served from another origin, apart if the server includes CORS headers, you won't be able to do that client-side. Did you take care of that ?

Comment: See [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: No, I haven't. Could you be explain how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://enable-cors.org/) on how to configure the requested server. If you can't change this server, you'll have to do the query server side, not browser-side.